# Get substring of parsed XML date

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml-parsing, substring

I simply need to get the substring from this parsed XML date

```
var cDateEnd = new Date(Date.parse(cDateEndXML));
```

Currently the output looks as follows:

```
Tue Jan 29 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (MST)
```

However all I need is

```
Tue Jan 29 2013
```

Whenever I add substring the console prints that it has no method 'substring'

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first convert it to a string.

```
var cDateEnd = new Date(Date.parse(cDateEndXML));
console.log(cDateEnd.toString().substring(0,15)); // prints "Tue Jan 29 2013"
```